# C++: how to declare non-function without defining it?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare something like an integer without defining it?

In C++, it is possible to separate the definition and declaration of a function.

```
// foo.cpp
int foo(int);

int foo(int a) {
  return 45;
}
```

But with a non-function it doesn't appear to be

```
// bar.cpp
int bar;
int bar = 10;
```

`bar.cpp` produces this

```
$ clang++ -c bar.cpp
bar.cpp:2:5: error: redefinition of 'a'
int a = 10;
    ^
bar.cpp:1:5: note: previous definition is here
int a;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Leaving off the type annotation on the second statement produces a different error.

```
// bar2.cpp
int bar;
bar = 10;
```

produces

```
$ clang++ -c bar2.cpp 
bar2.cpp:3:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
bar = 10;
^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
extern int bar; // declares, but does not define bar
int bar = 10;   // defines bar
```

Note that this requires `bar` to have static storage duration. Here's an example usage.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    extern int bar;
    std::cout << bar; // this should print 10
}

int bar = 10;
```

Comment: I spend an extra five seconds testing to make sure it works, and someone else beats me to it!